# Rewrite wildcard subdomains in .htaccess to corresponding folders on the main domain while preserving the subdomain

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, multi-subdomains

I'm trying to rewrite a subdomain to a folder/file like this:

- `name.example.com` -> `example.com/profile/name`
- `foo.example.com` -> `example.com/profile/foo`
- `xyzzy.example.com` -> `example.com/profile/xyzzy`

This is a wildcard subdomain pointing to the same folder as the main domain.

I have this code in .htaccess on the main domain root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#force https and non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# profile redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/profile/%1/ [L]
```

It works well but I want to keep the original URL: `name.example.com`

I have Internal Server Error when I try to change the last line to

```
RewriteRule (.*) /profile/%1/ [L]
```

I tried a couple different solutions without success. Obviously, I do it wrong.

How can I keep the original URL?

**Edit:**

---

This is a WordPress, so maybe the code after that is important:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It is not optimized but the problem is that everything between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` can be overwritten by Wordpress. This is why I don't want to put anything there.

Comment: I changed "redirect" to "rewrite" in a couple places in your question.   Redirects change the URL while rewrites show the from a different URL without changing the current URL.

Comment: And just to be clear, you have a wildcard virtual host configured such that the main domain and all the wildcard subdomains are hosted in the same folder on the server?

Comment: It is `profile`, not `agent`. Sorry, my error. I changed that in the question.

Comment: Yes, main domain and the wildcard subdomain points to the same folder on the server.

Answer (score 2):

> I have Internal Server Error when I try to change the last line to
>
> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) /agents/%1/ [L]
> ```

Because this will result in an internal rewrite loop. It looks like you also want to preserve the URL-path (which is presumably why you are capturing the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - but which is currently being discarded).

You need an additional condition to prevent a rewrite loop and modify the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example:

```
# profile redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /profile/%1/$1 [L]
```

Checking against an empty `REDIRECT_STATUS` (environment variable) ensures that only the initial request is rewritten, not the rewritten request.

This also assumes that the subdomains and main domain all point to the same place on the file system (as @Stephen asked in comments).

`$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

---

Alternatively, you could use a negated `RewriteRule` *pattern* and only rewrite requests that don't already start `/profile/` and use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the *substitution* instead (like you do in the canonical redirect). For example:

```
# profile redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^profile/ /profile/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The check against `REDIRECT_STATUS` is not required.

This behaves very similarly to the first rule block, except for one less `RewriteCond` directive. However, a slight caveat with this approach is that you couldn't have a requested URL-path that also starts `/profile/` (ie. that maps to a filesystem path like `/profile/profile/`) - although I imagine this is unlikely.

---

**UPDATE:** Since you are using WordPress, it's likely that WordPress itself is triggering an external redirect back to the canonical domain, eg. `example.com` (as defined by the `WP_HOME` PHP constants). What you can try, to prevent this, is to set the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` constants *dynamically* in `wp-config.php` to point to the hostname (ie. the subdomain) being requested, instead of being hardcoded to the main domain.

For example:

```
define('WP_SITEURL','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

(NB: This assumes HTTP, rather than HTTPS.)

Reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WP_SITEURL

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. The `agents` is my error. I changed it to `profile` in my original question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution. (Which you choose is up to you.)

Comment: The first solution end to the main domain: example.com.

Comment: The second solution return `Internal Server Error`. Maybe the WordPress cause the problem?

Comment: Ah, you've just mentioned that this is WordPress. The problem here is that WordPress itself will likely issue a redirect to `example.com` (the canonical domain). The directives I posted above are an internal rewrite - these would not trigger a redirect. What does the redirected URL-path look like?

Comment: So I need to change WordPress in order to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, most probably, I've updated my answer with some code you can try. (Alternatively, you can proxy the request using mod_proxy - although this is probably overkill, has security implications and ideally requires access to the server config.)

Comment: If it's creating an infinite redirect loop, is it because of the https:// before the url? (.*) will always equal https://? Can you do something like: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://(.*)\.example\.com [NC]

Comment: @Michaeld What makes you think there is a "redirect loop" here? (_Aside:_ The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the `Host` HTTP request header - this does not include the protocol. And the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the URL-path only, which also excludes the protocol.)

Comment: Please explain the downvote - mindless downvotes on seemingly correct answers - without explanation - are not helpful to anyone.